# ''AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome''' I am running file from terminal

Tags: python

I have been using the Selenium Webdriver with no issues. I ran this file perfectly fine 20 min ago and webbdriver.Chrome worked but now it is saying selenium.webdriver has no attribute chrome.

**Update I moved the file from my python dir to my home dir and now it works fine but in my python dir it says chrome doesn't have the attribute. How do I fix this?

***Update once I moved one of my other files into the home dir the previous ones are now not working again

****Update It turns out that my email.py file was causing an issue, does anyone know how that could work? Any dir that email.py was in would not work with the chromedriver but once removed they all work just fine. Please let me know so that I can avoid whatever happened in the future.

```
'''
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    zip_one =' '.join(sys.argv)[10:16]
    zip_two =' '.join(sys.argv)[16:]

#sys.argv_1 = sys.argv[10:15]
#sys.argv_2 = sys.argv[15:]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/'myname'/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com')
```

'''

It should work as it did 20 min ago, I have not changed any of the code.

Comment: Are you certain that the file is still present in that path? ***driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/'myname'/Downloads/chromedriver')***

Comment: Yes, I made sure it was still in my downloads. It was literally working one second then giving me the error the next.

Comment: Is this being executed on a Linux environment?

Comment: I’m on Mac OS X

Comment: Were you using sudo or other user-privilege modifiers to execute?  Perhaps the current execution doesn't have the rights to see the driver any longer.

Comment: No execution modifiers, there couldn’t be a chrome driver update or anything right?